# How to create additional launcher Icon(s) for same android app?

Tags: android

I have an application where I need to provide a additional icon acccessible in applications to launch an activity from the same application.

So that when application installs it shows two icons in the applications list, one icon to launch the app is already there, how to have the other icon and then how can I start the required activity from that icon/shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the manifest file inside the activity tag which you want to show in the launcher

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```